# User manual for Clementine music player

Tags: clementine

Is there a user manual for the Clementime music player?  The opening screen provides no hint of how to get it started.  It seems to assume lots of experience with other music players.

Comment: If unsure, you can look at where the package comes form (https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/clementine) which will take you to https://www.clementine-player.org/   Sorry I'm not aware of anything comprehensive...

Comment: Try the following:https://livingthelinuxlifestyle.wordpress.com/2020/02/28/clementine-music-player-tutorial/